# Weinstein fillings of a unit cotangent bundle

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, contact-geometry, contact-topology

Given a closed, orientable manifold M, and its unit cotangent bundle $ST^{\ast}M$. I wonder under which conditions $ST^{\ast}M$ admits a subcritical Weinstein filling?

Comment: I think that if $\chi(M)$ isn't 0 or ±1, then $ST^*M$ cannot be subcritically fillable. If $|\chi(M)| > m$, I think that the fibre is (non-trivial and) torsion in homology, so there's torsion in $H_{\dim M-1}(ST^*M)$. Suppose now $W$ is a subcritical filling: from the long exact sequence of the pair $(W,ST^*M)$, one should get that that group is torsion-free.

Comment: If $M=S^{2k+1}$ is a sphere, then $k=1$ or $3$.